# C++ Creating a thread results in an error?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors

I was working on a project and I ran into the problem of circular dependency. I originally wanted the Device class to send messages to one another using the Simulation class, and in order to do so, the Simulation class must have a recorded list of all created devices to send them the relayed message.

Anyway, I tried another method to fix the circular dependency problem using a middleman -- void RelayMessage(). It works fine until I uncomment the thread declaration. I have no idea why it gives me the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E1776   function "Device::Device(const Device &)" (declared
>   implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted
>   function  testingProject  c:\Users\osfer\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\testingProject\testingProject\main.cpp  37

Here's the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
static void RelayMessage(std::string message);


class Device {
public:
    std::string incomingMessage = "";
    std::string composedMessage;
    //std::thread inputStream;                      // uncommenting this creates an error in class Simulation @ line 36
    void relayMessage() {
        RelayMessage(composedMessage);
    }
    void InputStream() {
        while (true) {
            if (incomingMessage != "")
                printf("Message recieved!\n");
            incomingMessage = "";
        }
    }
};

class Simulation {
public:
    // record devices in simluation
    static std::vector<Device> devicesInSim;
    Simulation() {
        // create 2 devices
        devicesInSim.push_back(Device());
        devicesInSim.push_back(Device());
    }
};

static void RelayMessage(std::string message) {
    // relays message to all devices
    for (Device device : Simulation::devicesInSim)          // error
        device.incomingMessage = message;
}

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because `std::thread` doesn't have a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread).

Comment: Objects of type `std::thread` can’t be copied, only moved.

Comment: oh my god, thank you guys. I've been trying to figure out this problem for a couple of days!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to copy the object in your `for` loop. `thread` is not copyable. You should instead iterate using a reference:

```
static void RelayMessage(std::string message) {
    // relays message to all devices
    for (auto& device : Simulation::devicesInSim)
        device.incomingMessage = message;
}
```

(You can also use `Device&` instead of `auto&`, but `auto` is pretty clear here.)

And this is probably what you had in mind anyway. Without the reference, you're changing `incomingMessage` on copies of the objects rather than on the actual objects contained in the vector. When using range-based `for` loops, you need to keep in mind that this iterates over copies of the elements in the container:

```
for (auto i : container)
```

To iterate over the actual objects, use:

```
for (auto& i : container)
```

And for read-only access to the elements, use:

```
for (const auto& i : container)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments and other answers, `std::thread` does not have a copy constructor and hence you need to pass by reference to work with them.

Another example is when working with files, i.e. `fstream`. You cannot pass `fstream` objects into a function since there is no copy constructor. Essentially what happens is that when you pass objects into a function, a copy is made which is local to the function only (known as pass by value).

Since `thread`, `fstream` etc do not have copy constructors, a copy cannot be made during the function call. Hence, you have to pass by reference using `&` with the data type.

**EDIT:**
This is not exactly a solution to your problem, but some insights into it so that you know the reason if it ever happens next time.